# App is not compatible with device on googole store

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

the device is tablet samsung tab s smt705

some part of my manifest. I did not have any of the uses feature included now thats on store,i also didn't have supports-screens tag on the one which is on store. plus the minsdkversion i had it 8 on store...
 should uses feature fix the issue? support-screens and minsdkverssion fix issue? what could be reason down to this?

> ```
> <supports-screens
>     android:anyDensity="true"
>     android:largeScreens="true"
>     android:normalScreens="true"
>     android:smallScreens="true"
>     android:xlargeScreens="true" />
> <uses-sdk
>     android:minSdkVersion="10"
>     android:targetSdkVersion="20" />  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PHONE_STATE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
> <uses-permission 
>  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
>   <uses-feature
>     android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"
>     android:required="false" />
> <uses-feature
>     android:name="android.hardware.location"
>     android:required="false" />
> <uses-feature
>     android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
>     android:required="false" />
>  <uses-feature
>     android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
>     android:required="false" />
>   <uses-feature
>     android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
>     android:required="false" />
> <uses-feature
>     android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
>     android:required="false" />
> <uses-feature
>     android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
>     android:required="true" />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you use this in manifest?

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:maxSdkVersion="20"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
```

Comment: i used this on store  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" and changed it to 10 the minsdkversion. and while i added this as well now <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Trilarion Why not? Robo-review much?